# Can I import from TS 2.x typings written in TS 1.x?

Tags: typescript, systemjs, commonjs, babeljs, typescript-typings

I started learning Typescript couple days ago, it's been quite confusing so far, especially with modules.

I'm importing typings using `npm install -s @types/knockout`, but most of the typings availlable are still written in Typescript 1.

Here is a typing definition from es6-promise package:

```
declare module 'es6-promise' {
var foo: typeof Promise; // Temp variable to reference Promise in local context
namespace rsvp {
    export var Promise: typeof foo;
    export function polyfill(): void;
}
export = rsvp;
}
```

Is there a way to import the default export specified as `export = xxx` from typescript 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use them. Unfortunately, TypeScript has adopted a backward looking approach to ES Modules instead of a forward looking one.

```
export = rsvp
```

is not a default export.

A default export would have the form

```
export default rsvp;
```

`export =` is a TypeScript CommonJS specific construct that implies assignment to the `module.exports` property available of CommonJS modules.

In order to import it as the default, you will need to do two things.

1. set `"allowSyntheticDefualtImports": true` in your **tsconfig.json**
2. use an ES Module <-> CommonJS Module interop aware runtime such as SystemJS and/or pipe your code through Babel in another build step